# FlatList как сделать мульти строки

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

как сделать такой вывод записей в react native?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Искал решения в FLatList. Нашел вариант с использованием 2-х FlatList-ов и создание нового массива